# WP8 Voice Command Definition file multiple languages

Tags: windows-phone-8, voice

When building a VCD you define the languages like so:

```
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-US">
  ...
</CommandSet>

<CommandSet xml:lang="ja-JP">
  ...
</CommandSet>
```

My question is, if I want multiple languages to use the same CommandSet (such as `en-US` and `en-GB`) is that possible without copy/paste?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The option listed in this answer doesn't work. It seems the best way to avoid VCD multi-langage copy-paste is to use T4 templates to generate VCDs are compile time.

---

Yep, that's actually pretty simple. As long as you don't have CommandSets overlapping  you can create a CommandSet for the entire language without mentioning a specific region. Remember, `xml:lang` is a generic XML attribute and you can use that to your advantage.

In the code snippet below we'll specify an `en` (English) voice command set without the need to mention specific regions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0">

  <CommandSet xml:lang="en">
    <Example> English example </Example>
    <!-- ... -->
  </CommandSet>

  <CommandSet xml:lang="es-ES">
    <Example> Non-english example </Example>       
    <!-- ... -->    
  </CommandSet>

</VoiceCommands>
```

When we run this code snippet we can see the different Example text showing up in different emulators:

[image: VoiceCommands with es-ES text]
[image: VoiceCommand with en text]

One limitation here is that you can't have a `xml:lang="en"` CommandSet at the same time as region specific english CommandSets (e.g. `xml:lang="en-us"`). For the overwhelming majority of apps, that's fine. If you're however embedding a region specific PhraseList you'll have to use alternative strategies (e.g. list of movies only available in specific regions due to copyright restrictions) . One option I've seen before is a T4 template generating a VCD file instead of having a repetitive copy-paste VCD file.

Comment: Justing, when I update my voice definition file with xml:lang="en" and sets the phone to use en-gb voice, the commands are not visible in the "What can I say dialog". Any idea ?

Comment: Yeah this didn't work for me either.  I set `xml:lang="en"` and it works with my phone set to US voice but not set to UK voice.  I also tried the emulator, set the Country to UK and voice to UK but my app commands do not show up in the "What can I say" dialog (they do with everything set to US).

Comment: Yep, you're right the CommandSet with xml:lang="en" is only entered as en-US.

Comment: It seems like it should work though... we should complain to MS :)

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer possible. With WP8.1 you MUST supply the xml:lang.